# What happens to partially uploaded files?

Tags: upload

Sometimes users would upload a very large file such as 10MB or so and it fails in the middle because one reason or another. My question is, what happens then?

For example, if it fails at the 5MB mark - permanently failed because of failed internet connection, would it still take up 5MB of disk space? Where would the partially uploaded file be? How can I purge it?

I meant web upload - the upload via HTML upload control.

Comment: How are the files uploaded? FTP? SCP/SFTP? Web-Upload?

Comment: More detail is needed to provide any sort of answer, the lack of detail may also lead to this question being closed. Please revise you question with more detail, as Simon points out the method of upload would be a required piece of information.

Comment: @SimonStrasser, question updated. I meant ordinary users who upload stuff via the native HTML upload control.

Comment: @kavoir.com - Using what programming language? php?

Answer (score 4):

It depends entirely on the receiving application.

- Most FTP/SFTP servers would keep the partial file under the assumption that the client will resume the transfer later.
- SCP is about 50/50 in my experience. I assume because it's a configurable option and different distros have decided on different defaults, but I haven't actually looked in to this.
- Windows servers using SMB will delete the partial file.

And that's about it for well-known behaviors. Anything else is implementation specific.